# Generically putting every component of a tuple inside Maybe

Tags: haskell

I want a function that, given any tuple, returns a tuple of the same shape in which every component `x` has become `Just x`.

For example, `maybeizeProduct ('a', 'b')` should return `(Just 'a',Just 'b')`.

`maybeizeProduct` should work for tuples of any (reasonable) number of components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `generics-sop` solution is very nice, but it's not unusual to see this done, in actual practice, with type classes and boilerplate up to some reasonable tuple size.  (At least, that's how I see it done in a lot of high-quality library code, like `lens`.)

So, for completeness, here's a no-generics solution using a type class with an associated type family to define the maybeized type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class ToMaybe a where
  type AsMaybe a
  toMaybe :: a -> AsMaybe a
```

and a series of tedious boilerplate definitions:

```
instance ToMaybe (a,b) where
  type AsMaybe (a,b) = (Maybe a, Maybe b)
  toMaybe (a,b) = (Just a, Just b)
instance ToMaybe (a,b,c) where
  type AsMaybe (a,b,c) = (Maybe a, Maybe b, Maybe c)
  toMaybe (a,b,c) = (Just a, Just b, Just c)
instance ToMaybe (a,b,c,d) where
  type AsMaybe (a,b,c,d) = (Maybe a, Maybe b, Maybe c, Maybe d)
  toMaybe (a,b,c,d) = (Just a, Just b, Just c, Just d)
-- etc.
```

giving:

```
λ> toMaybe (1,3)
(Just 1,Just 3)
λ> toMaybe (1,3,4)
(Just 1,Just 3,Just 4)
```

Optionally, the boilerplate can be generated with Template Haskell.  Due to stage restrictions, we'd need to define a module containing the class itself and the TH instance generator:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module MaybeTuplesHelper where

import Control.Monad
import Language.Haskell.TH

class ToMaybe a where
  type AsMaybe a
  toMaybe :: a -> AsMaybe a

mkToMaybeInstance n = do
  nms <- replicateM n $ newName "a"
  let -- typ: (a1, a2, a3)
      typ  = foldl appT (tupleT n) . map varT $ nms
      -- mtyp: (Maybe a1, Maybe a2, Maybe a3)
      mtyp = foldl appT (tupleT n) . map (appT (conT (mkName "Maybe")) . varT) $ nms
      -- pat: (a1, a2, a3)
      pat  = tupP . map varP $ nms
      -- mexp: (Just a1, Just a2, Just a3)
      mexp  = tupE . map (appE (conE (mkName "Just")) . varE) $ nms
  [d| instance ToMaybe $(typ) where
        type AsMaybe $(typ) = $(mtyp)
        toMaybe $(pat) = $(mexp)
    |]
```

and then generate the instance themselves (up to 15-tuples here) in a separate module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import MaybeTuplesHelper

concat <$> mapM mkToMaybeInstance [2..15]
```

and it seems to work:

```
λ> :l MaybeTuples
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( MaybeTuples.hs, interpreted ) [flags changed]
Ok, modules loaded: Main, MaybeTuplesHelper (/scratch/buhr/stack/global-project/.stack-work/odir/MaybeTuplesHelper.o).
Collecting type info for 2 module(s) ... 
λ> toMaybe (1,2,3,4,5,"six")
(Just 1,Just 2,Just 3,Just 4,Just 5,Just "six")
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with [generics-sop](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop). Some preliminary extensions and imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-partial-type-signatures #-}
import Generics.SOP
import Generics.SOP.NP (trans_NP)
```

We define this auxiliary typeclass that relates each type with its "maybeized" version:

```
class (b ~ Maybe a) => Maybeized a b where
  maybeize :: a -> b

instance Maybeized a (Maybe a) where
  maybeize = Just
```

Here is the generic function:

```
maybeizeProduct ::
  forall xr xs yr ys.
  ( IsProductType xr xs,
    IsProductType yr ys,
    AllZip Maybeized xs ys
  ) =>
  xr ->
  yr
maybeizeProduct = productTypeTo @yr 
                . trans_NP (Proxy @Maybeized) (mapII maybeize) 
                . productTypeFrom @xr
```

[`productTypeFrom`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.5.0.0/docs/Generics-SOP.html#v:productTypeFrom) and [`productTypeTo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.5.0.0/docs/Generics-SOP.html#v:productTypeTo) convert tuples to and from the anonymous product representation [`NP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-SOP-NP.html#t:NP) used by generics-sop.

The central function is [`trans_NP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-SOP-NP.html#v:trans_NP) that lets us change the "index list" of the product, where the [`AllZip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-SOP-Constraint.html#t:AllZip) constraint ensures that the input and output index lists have the same shape and we can perform the transformation for each element.

Putting it to work:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ (maybeizeProduct ('a', 'b') :: (_, _))
  print $ (maybeizeProduct ('a', 'b', 'c') :: (_, _, _))
```

Because the function is so generic, we need to give some hint that we want a tuple return type.